# What is time complexity for this solution?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

this is a solution for leetcode problem 566. reshape matrix,
I want to know the time complexity and if can modify it for better,
I think its complexity is O(N)

```
var matrixReshape = function (mat, r, c) {
  if (mat.length * mat[0].length !== r * c) return mat;
  mat = mat.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    for (let i of cur) {
      acc.push(i);
    }
    return acc;
  });

  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < mat.length; i += c) {
    result.push(mat.slice(i, c + i));
  }

  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is O(n) and you can't get better than that. But you could skip the step of creating a one dimensional array and fill the target matrix directly. In javascript it is a bit ugly because there are no integers and integer division.

```js
const n = mat[0].length, ret = []
let pos = 0
for (let i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    const row = []
    for (let j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        // other languages with integer division: ret[i][j] = mat[pos / n][pos % n]
        row.push(mat[Math.floor(pos / n)][pos % n])
        pos++
    }
    ret.push(row)
}
```

Alternatively you can have indexes for row and column of original matrix and if the column index becomes the same as the number of columns in the original array you reset it and increment the row index.